# Use of 'audience' for a single person

Tags: grammar

Can I say 'He was my audience', or 'He was the audience' if I ended up presenting to only one person in a meeting?

Comment: If only one person 'gives ear' : that's your audience.

Comment: English is heavily dependant upon context. You could say "He was my audience" in certain contexts (and depending upon what you actually mean by "was") but probably not in others.

Comment: Yes, it depends - as ever - on the context. Give us more context and you'll get a more reliable answer. It is common in the UK, and the word 'was' is generally stressed because you are being **jocular**. "At the end this German guy asked a lot of questions". "What about the rest of the/your audience?" "He **was** the/my audience!" I have never heard it used in a completely serious context.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel, Greybeard, Old Brixtonian.  I was looking to use it in a serious context.  I was e-mailing a colleague who was preparing a presentation and wanted to tell him that a key person should be treated as the audience for it.  From your comments I believe it should be fine to say 'So and so will be the audience'.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=an+audience+of+one&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20audience%20of%20one%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The technical term is _Addressee_. The addressee of any utterance is whoever the speaker intends to hear it (whether they do or not, and whether anybody else does or not). Second person (_you_) refers to addressees.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the word *audience* for one person alone, but only if the nature of the event is such that there could have been, and normally would have been, more people attending it, and it just happened that nobody else showed up on the particular occasion. For example, suppose that a public lecture was announced, only one person came to attend it, and the lecture nevertheless went ahead in front of that one person sitting alone in the lecture hall. It could then be said that there was only one person in the audience; that would be perfectly correct, literal use of the word *audience*.  The word would, however, not be used when speaking of the communications that are by their nature directed at one person only.

The phrase *audience of one* is more often used metaphorically, in the cases in which, even though there are many people in the audience in the literal sense, the opinion of only one among them really matters, and everything is therefore geared towards having a certain effect on that person. Religious people sometimes narrow this metaphorical sense to a more specific metaphor: they say that in living one's life one is performing for the audience of one, to convey that idea that it is only God's opinion of one's life that ultimately matters.

If one is considering using the phrase *audience of one* literally, one needs to be mindful of the prevalence of its metaphorical uses.

Comment: It's fuzzy: I have read about strange experimental theatre works which might be performed in a car or a hen-house or something, and it might only have room for the performer(s) and one spectator, but audience seems fine then. Other situations, such as a lap-dance, are often designed around only having one person watching; I guess you would describe them as the audience.

Comment: @StuartF, yes, these are conceptually interesting cases. I would argue that referring to such performances as *theatre* and *dance* already stretches the concepts of theatre and dance (and in the case of lap dances perhaps functions as a euphemism), and that the stretching of the concept of an audience when speaking about them is then probably done for the sake of consistency with describing them as theatre or dance.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, this is correct.**

Like the word team, audience is a *collective noun*, which means doesn't matter how many people attend your performance, they will be collectively referred to as *the audience*.

> A  collective noun refers to a type of noun that encompasses “a whole group as a single entity” as well as the members of that group. It is considered singular in form. (dictionary.com)

Comment: Hello, Nicholas, if you still dip in. 'A **pride** of lions' uses the collective noun 'pride', but a pride will never consist of a single lion.